# How to register touch move over events in Angular?

Tags: angular, touch, hammer.js

**Summarize the problem**

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-touch-playground

I'm trying register touch events and want to be able to touch my finger, drag and lift my finger resulting in every `td` of a table touched to be highlighted. This seems to be recorded as a `pan` event

I've used a dictionary `pressed` when any of the events `click, touch, etc` registers and `[class.bg-warning]="pressed[i]"` to highlight these.

Is there a way to register each `td` touched?

I've tried events like `click, touchstart`
and `hammerjs` events (in `app.module.ts` I've imported via `import 'hammerjs';`) but I have to click every `td` to highlight it.

```
<td *ngFor="let dummy of ' '.repeat(48).split(''), let i = index"
    (press)="logPress(i)"
    (mouseenter)="logMouseIn(i)"
    (touchmove)="logTouchmove(i)"
    (click)="logClick(i)"
    (touch)="logTouch(i)"
    (touchend)="logTouchend(i)"
    (hover)="logHover(i)"
    (touchstart)="logTouchstart(i)"
    (touchend)="logTouchend(i)"
    (touchcancel)="logTouchcancel(i)"
    [class.bg-warning]="pressed[i]" >
</td>
```

*example of setting `pressed` dictionary:*

```
logClick(i: number) {
 this.event += '\n Click: '+ i.toString();
 this.pressed[i]=1;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Stackblitz** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-touch-playground-pan-events

**Change required** - The key here is that if I were to do

```
(pan)="logPan(i)"
```

within the `td` then no matter the pan event would log the same `i` as the where the pan started.

Whereas if I do this

```
(pan)="logPan($event)"
```

I can access the `$event` coordinates `(x, y)` via `evt.center.x / evt.center.y`.

**Utilizing coordinates** - To convert the coordinates `(x, y)` to the `td` I care about I've used the [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) method which *returns the topmost Element at the specified coordinates (relative to the viewport)* and I've added an accessible attribute `id` to each `td` so that I can set my `pressed` dictionary, which is logging the `td` touched.

```
logPan(evt: any) {
  this.event += '\n Touch Pan: '+ `(${evt.center.x}, ${evt.center.y}, ${document.elementFromPoint(evt.center.x, evt.center.y).id})`
  this.pressed[document.elementFromPoint(evt.center.x, evt.center.y).id]=1;
}
```

**Additional** - pan doesn't seem to pick up where the finger first starts so an addtional `(touchstart)="logTouchstart(i)"` is required.

**Credit** - I figured this out after looking at the Stackblitz on the following blog: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/gestures-in-an-angular-application-dde71804c0d0

Comment: evt.center.x and evt.center.y really helped me. Helpful answer :)